# ASP.net 4.5 copy the current auto-generated MachineKey to another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cryptography, asp.net-4.5

I have an ASP.net 4.5 application that is running with an auto-generated machine key. I need to spin up another server and I want to set it's machine key to be the same as the other, so tokens and logins can persist across both servers. Is there an effective way to retrieve the auto-generated machine key for use on another server?

To clarify, I can't re-gen a new key and set it on both servers, as that would invalidate any existing tokens in the wild. I am trying to find a way to accomplish this without invalidating any existing tokens.

Comment: You shouldn't need to store that key. Just generate one separately and set it to both sites.

Comment: The problem with that, is that any existing user tokens, will not validate against the newly generated key

Comment: Correct. They will have to log in again. But just once. One reason it's good to consider generating a specific code up front.

Comment: Wait a second; I just remembered something: isn't the auto generated key generated every time the AppDomain restarts? That's one of the reasons I started setting one on my sites way back...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is actually possible to retrieve the machine keys, or it might be quite tricky. You may really want to assess how much of a deal it is to set new keys.

Keys are stored in the Local Security  Authority managed in Windows and are stored encrypted in the registry.

The article below gives an example for decrypting thee stored values.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/06/use-powershell-to-decrypt-lsa-secrets-from-the-registry.aspx

It also references the following page with the C# version of the same code

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LSARetrievePrivateData.html